# How to get the values of the outliers and their coordinates from a box plot

Tags: matlab

Is it possible to call a property of `boxplot` to get the values of outliers and the element coordinates of the outliers - if the data was a matrix ?

For the sake of this example let's say I have this data array showing two outliers, how would I do it?

```
A = [ -2 -1 2 2.1 2.2 2.5 2.6 2.8 3 3.2 3.4 3.5 4.2 4.5 5];

figure(1)
s = subplot(6,1,1:5);
o = boxplot(A, 'whisker', 1.5);
title('A')
axis(s,[0 2 -3 7])

s1 = subplot(6,1,6);
plot(A,0,'bo')
axis(s1,[-3 7 -1 1])
set(s1,'YTickLabel',[],'YTick',[])

%@chappjc posted a working method
s_Outliers = findobj(o,'Tag','Outliers');
outliers_of_A = get(s_Outliers,'YData');
disp('The values of the outliers');
disp(outliers_of_A);
```

Thanks for the answers - it works perfectly. 
@chappjc posted a working method - using this Would it be possible to remove the values of outliers_of_A form A ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The handle for the outlier markers contains the actual outlier data.  Create your `boxplot`, saving the handles structure as an output argument.  As of R2014a, the outliers handle is the last in the list (if no notches are displayed) or second to last (if notches are displayed), but you can use `findobj` to be sure:

```
>> hb = boxplot(A, 'whisker', 1.5);
>> hOutliers = findobj(hb,'Tag','Outliers');
>> yy = get(hOutliers,'YData')
yy =
    -2    -1
```

Comment: @user1320058 I'm glad this worked for you, thanks for accepting it as the best answer for you. Feel free to also up-vote the answer if you feel inclined. :)

Comment: would it be possible to remove the values of yy form A ?

Comment: Sure, delete them off the box plot with `delete(hOutliers)`, remove them from `A` with `A = setdiff(A,yy)`.  Can you vote up the answer (click on the up arrow above the number)?

Answer (score 2):

While @chappjc has given an excellent answer on how this can be done using the Boxplot object itself, I present below the mathematical way of doing it:

```
Q1 = quantile(A,0.25);
Q3 = quantile(A,0.75);
Spread = 1.5*(Q3-Q1);
MaxValue = Q3 + Spread;
MinValue = Q1 - Spread;
A( A>MaxValue | A<MinValue)
ans =

-2    -1
```

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to get the index of the outlier value is by using the method "isoutlier()"

```
TF = isoutlier(A,'mean') % The method 'mean' is the same used by the boxplot for getting the outlier values

%this will give you a true/false vector

outlier_index = find(TF==1)

%Here you have the index of your outlier

oulier_values = A(oulier_index)
```